# How to group_concat() and group by with null values?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables like this:

publications

```
publications id        |  publications field id | publications description
1000                   |  1                     | John 
1000                   |  2                     | 2014
1000                   |  4                     | aa@...
1000                   |  6                     | 123-456-789
```

id = 1000 means one book and its detail description (author name, year, e-mail,tel)

registry

```
   publications field id  | component
    1                      | author name
    2                      | year
    3                      | date
    4                      | e-mail
    5                      | price
    6                      | tel
```

registry means a book's format table

I want to merge 2 tables like this:

```
publications id | publications description
1000            | John,2014,NULL,aa@..,NULL,123-456-789
```

NULL means this `book(id=1000)`'s field id `3` and `5` is NULL

So, I use the left join:

```
SELECT registry.publications field id,component,publications id, publications description
FROM registry 
LEFT JOIN  publications
on publications.publications field id = registry.publications field id
```

but the result is:

```
publications field id  | component   | publications id   | publications description
1                      | author name | 1000              | John
2                      | year        | 1000              | 2014
3                      | date        | NULL              | NULL
4                      | e-mail      | 1000              | aa@..
5                      | price       | NULL              | NULL
6                      | tel         | 1000              | 123-456-789
```

I know the next step is use the `group_concat(IFNULL(publications description,'NULL'))`
but how to group by `publications id`? When some `publications id` is NULL?

Comment: Dear J.Lucky: I do not know how to modify this!!! Thank you very much !!Help me a lot.

Comment: No problem Lydia. Glad to help. :) For more info about formatting, please refer to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting